# Safe C structs serialization for sending over networks? - C++

Tags: c++, networking, serialization, struct

How would someone go about serializing C-style structs independent of the CPU endianness?

I've searched for solutions, but I was hoping for a more general solution to the problem rather than changing the byte-order of each field in the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no general solution to this problem within the language (or common system libraries).

(There might be scripts/tools that could autogen the read/write code for you, or libraries that could add a sort of "reflection" to your structs, but I don't have references for you.)

Bonus info that should be in any good answer to this question: In addition to endianness, make sure you use compiler directives to lock in the packing of the struct in memory to byte-aligned (which is normal for network packets) instead of the natural alignment of the struct fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a binary stream, then you do have to deal with the associated problems including endianness.  For the sake of presenting an alternative, you can create a human-readable/ASCII representation of fields - that tends to avoid many of the pitfalls but is often more verbose and less performant.  Either way, it's a bit of a pain to create the functions when there are lots of struct/fields.  You can consider code generation using a support script, even driving that off metadata from GCC-XML, Open-C++ (if your C code is a legal C++ program too) or similar....